# Python 2.7.16+ Import Error : No module named sillyLibrary

Tags: python-2.7

My problem is when I running program from python. It said that "Import error : No module named sillyLibrary". Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide more inputs such as IDE, the environment you are running the python code etc. Also did you install the required package sillyLibrary? using PIP INSTALL?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eUeAwZPg

Comment: I already use pip install. But it can't install it

Comment: whats that command you used, and whats the error msg you are getting. I checked here https://github.com/classam/silly and its suggested pip install silly? Are you sure the library name is sillyLibrary?

Comment: just same as you share to me but it doesn't work

Comment: https://ibb.co/dmJmvdn